# Changing embedded Tomcat from v6 to v7 causes InitialContext lookup to fail

Tags: tomcat, jndi

I'm using JUnit test cases to exercise my web service using embedded Tomcat. Under Tomcat 6 everything was working fine, but when I switched my project to Tomcat 7 I'm coming unstuck.

The test code to setup the embedded Tomcat server is as follows:

#### Tomcat 6

```
Embedded container = new Embedded();
container.setCatalinaHome("C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 7.0.11");
container.setRealm(new MemoryRealm());
container.setName("Catalina");
Engine engine = container.createEngine();
container.addEngine(engine);
Host host = container.createHost("localhost", "/DecoderServiceTest");
Context rootContext = container.createContext("/DecoderServiceTest", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/build/web");
host.addChild(rootContext);
engine.setName("Catalina");
engine.addChild(host);
engine.setDefaultHost("localhost");
container.addEngine(engine);
Connector connector = container.createConnector(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 4321, false);
container.addConnector(connector);
container.start();
```

As the embedded API has changed between versions 6 and 7, I've changed my own code to the following:

#### Tomcat 7

```
Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
tomcat.setBaseDir("C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 7.0.11");
tomcat.setPort(1234);
tomcat.addWebApp("/DecoderServiceTest", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/build/web");
tomcat.setHostname("localhost");
tomcat.start();
```

The actual web service starts up fine when I execute the JUnit test (I can use my web browser and see the WSDL being served up).

However, in the constructor of my web service I intialise some variables based on the values in the `web.xml` file (which is located in `System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/build/web/WEB-INF/web.xml"`), as follows:

```
  Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
  Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
  int thumbnailSize = (Integer) envCtx.lookup("thumbnail-pixel-size");
```

Where my `web.xml` file contains the following entry:

```
<env-entry>
  <env-entry-name>thumbnail-pixel-size</env-entry-name>
  <env-entry-type>java.lang.Integer</env-entry-type>
  <env-entry-value>64</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

When I try and create the `envCtx` object I get a [NamingException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/naming/NamingException.html) with the message that `Name java:comp is not bound in this Context`. I'm confused because it worked fine with Tomcat 6. Have I missed something in the setup of Tomcat 7 that I had previously defined in the setup of Tomcat 6?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mark Thomas via the tomcat-users mailing list [suggested](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201105.mbox/%3C4DBFF366.3050508@apache.org%3E)

```
tomcat.enableNaming();
```

before the server is started. This worked for me (I guess they changed the default behaviour between 6 and 7).